# Web-push + NodeJs en Firefox no funciona

Tags: nodejs, push-notification, firefox, notificaciones

Seguí los pasos para implementar las notificaciónes desde esta pagina de [Desarrolladores](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user) y funciona excelentemente en Chrome y Edge.

El serviceWorker.register funciona correctamente en todos los navegadores, pero cuando intento mandar una notificación a un cliente Firefox, el servidor me arroja este mensaje:

```
{"code": 401, "errno": 109, "error": "Unauthorized", "more_info": "http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes", "message": "Request did not validate missing authorization header"}
```

Mi servidor corre en NodeJs, usando [web-push npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push) configurado de esta manera:

```
webpush.setVapidDetails(
  'mailto:micorreo@gmail.com',
  process.env.PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY,
  process.env.PRIVATE_VAPID_KEY,
);
```

Cuando mando nitificaciones hago esto:

```
let subscriptionObject = {
    endpoint: 'https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/wpush/v2/gAAAAABfKYfR0dFJuaE2Eotq8gL....',
    keys: {
      auth: 'sadasd.....',
      p256dh: 'asdasdasd....'
    }
}

let payload = {
    title: 'Mi Notif',
    message: 'Hello world',
  }

webpush.sendNotification(subscriptionObject, payload)
```

En la documentación encotré los [errores](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/common-issues-and-reporting-bugs#firefox_and_mozilla_autopush) que arroja Firefox, pero las credenciales ahí están, o me falta agregar algo?

De antemano Gracias. :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo logrué, modifiqué mi archivo .env
anteriormente se encontraba así:

```
PRIVATE_VAPID_KEY=A2Ezk...;
PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY=BAe8fsj2LWd3J....;
```

Por alguna razón funcionaba en Chrome, Opera y Edge. Después agregué comillas y quité punto y coma:
`PRIVATE_VAPID_KEY='A2Ezk...'`
`PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY='BAe8fsj2LWd3J....'`